# Problems with cout in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, ostream

To start, I want to show you my code below.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    float num = 3;
    std::ios_base::fmtflags initial;
    initial = std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed);
    std::cout.setf(initial);
    std::cout<<num;
}
```

The output is 3.000000. With only first and last lines output is 3. My book says that "The setf() method returns a copy of all the formatting settings in effect before the
call was made. std::ios_base::fmtflags is a fancy name for the type needed to store this
information. So the assignment to initial stores the settings that were in place before
the setf function was called. The initial variable can then be used as an argument to setf() to reset all the formatting settings to this original value." But as you can see, it doesn't work. What's the issue?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than creating them with default values and immediately overwriting the defaults. In this case, that means changing `std::ios_base::fmtflags initial; initial = std::cout.setfstd::ios_base::fixed);` to `std::ios_base::fmtflags initial = std::cout.setfstd::ios_base::fixed);`.

Answer (score 3):

From [std::ios_base::setf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf):

> `fmtflags setf( fmtflags flags );`
> (1)
> `fmtflags setf( fmtflags flags, fmtflags mask );`
> (2)
> Sets the formatting flags to specified settings.
>
> 1. Sets the formatting flags identified by flags. Effectively the following operation is performed **fl = fl | flags** where fl defines the state of internal formatting flags.
> 2. Clears the formatting flags under mask, and sets the cleared flags to those specified by flags. Effectively the following operation is performed fl = (fl & ~mask) | (flags & mask) where fl defines the state of internal formatting flags.

(Emphasize is mine.)

So, `std::ios::setf()` is a good choice to set individual flags but it's a bad choice to set all flags at once.

For this, [std::ios_base::flags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) is the right tool:

> `fmtflags flags() const;`
> (1)
> `fmtflags flags( fmtflags flags );`
> (2)
> Manages format flags.
>
> 1. returns current formatting setting
> 2. replaces current settings with given ones.

Sample:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    float num = 3;
    std::cout<<num<<'\n';
    std::ios_base::fmtflags initial;
    initial = std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed);
    std::cout.flags(initial); // <-- the fix
    std::cout<<num<<'\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3
3
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae5cdcc713b04096)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the format flags are mutually **exclusive**.

For example, `std::ios_base::left` can not be used together `std::ios_base::right`. `std::ios_base::fixed` is an exclusive flags also. It can not be used with `std::ios_base::scientific`. To exclusively set a format flag, `std::ios_base::setf()` takes additional bit group flag as its second parameter. You can then set a format flag correctly. `std::ios_base::fixed` is a group of `std::ios_base::floatfield` and you should set it as its second parameter when calling setf().

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    float num = 3;

    std::ios_base::fmtflags initial;
    initial = std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
    std::cout.setf(initial, std::ios_base::floatfield);

    std::cout << num;  // 3 printed on VS2019

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The book, "Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales - 1.2.3 The Format Parameters of a Stream" was referred to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use **[io manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)**. (It's also more readable code):

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    float num = 3;
    
    std::cout<< std::fixed;
    
    std::cout << num<<'\n';
    std::cout<<num<<'\n';
    
    std::cout << std::scientific;

    std::cout << num<<'\n';
    std::cout<<num<<'\n';
    
    std::cout << std::defaultfloat;

    std::cout << num<<'\n';
    std::cout<<num<<'\n';
```

}

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9e7f5fbdbd8c955)

Output:

```
3.000000
3.000000
3.000000e+00
3.000000e+00
3
3
```

Answer (score 1):

`setf` is used to set a *specific* format flag. So it does not reset the set `fixed` flag when you call `std::cout.setf(initial);`
You probably want to use the [flags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) function instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const double num = 3.0;
    std::cout << num << '\n';
    const auto initial_flags = std::cout.flags(std::ios_base::fixed);
    std::cout << num << '\n';
    std::cout.flags(initial_flags);
    std::cout << num << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3
3.000000
3
```